# Unit testing "object reference not set to an instance " at NUnit

Tags: nunit, unit-testing

i have a ASP.Net project and Nunitasp framework work for unit testing,i have a object in account.aspx.cs file when i tried to test the object(NugetplatformModel) value i get"object reference not set to an instance" error, 
my account page code is given below

```
 public partial class Account : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public NugetPlatformModel NugetPlatformModels;
    public string result = string.Empty;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            Response.Redirect("/login", true);
        }
        else
        {
            result = "success";
            NugetPlatformModels = new NugetPlatformModel();
        }
```

}

my test case code is given below

```
        [Test]
    public void AccountPage_ValidCredential_AccessModel()
    {
        Browser.GetPage(domain + "account");
        string ExpectedPage = domain + "account";
        logon();
        Account acccountPage = new Account();
        AssertEquals("success", acccountPage.result);
        AssertEquals("should have license",true,acccountPage.NugetPlatformModels.IsHavingLicense);

    }
```

How can I access and test that code behind variables? when start the testing the NUgetplatformmodel has been assigned i have checked it by debugging but after that in nunit gui it displays null reference error, i thought there is a problem in accessing variable in testcase..please help me..

Comment: *where* (i.e. which line) is the NullReferenceException thrown? It's much harder to help you without that information.

Comment: AssertEquals("success", acccountPage.result);
        AssertEquals("should have license",true,acccountPage.NugetPlatformModels.IsHavingLicense);

these two lines gets exception in nunit testing, thanks for your response..

Answer (score 2):

It seems your code is not complete. From what I see here your account needs to run Page_Load in order to fill result and NugetPlatformModels. But I do not see how this method is launched in your test. Is it run from the constructor of Account?

It would be helpfull if you put all the code for Account in your post.